# How we can save java file without name

Tags: java

I want save my Java file without name and i want compile or run that file. Is this is possible in Java or not?

Example:

```
class A {
  public void display() {
    System.out.println("Hello ..How are you..??");
  }
}
```

I want save this file name as `.java` only (without any name before the extension). Is this is possible in Java and if it is possible than how we can compile this file without name through cmd?

Comment: What are you asking? What is a file without a name?

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: Even if you could make the name be just `.java`, which I doubt, that's just begging for trouble.

Comment: I have **NO IDEA** what you are talking about.

Comment: Java class names must match the file name. So what, you're gonna have a class without a name too?

Comment: @JoshM, he's asking whether you can have a Java file with the name `.java` which would imply a public class with no name.

Comment: @sushain97 Oh. Up to my extent, that isn't possible (as the other comments suggest)

Comment: Class name must match the file name. Without a class name you wouldn't be able to reference it. This definitely won't work, will throw syntax errors everywhere.

Comment: @JoshM @sage88, works fine as long as it's not declared `public` (check my answer).

Comment: Yeah just took a look, you're right. Not sure why you'd ever want to do this, but sure enough it is possible without public :).

Comment: I want to save my java fine with .java extension only not with any name. Like if we have file.java but i want to save my file with only .java not want give any name. Is it is possible in java. If possible than how we can compile and run this file from cmd.

Answer (score 7):

It appears to be possible! For my surprise, your example just compiled fine. (I've used 1.7)

`javac .java` command produced `A.class` in same directory.

However, if you declare your `'A'` class as `public` it will not be possible. (In Java, all classes declared as public must be stored with file name as public class name)

Comment: I want to save my java fine with .java extension only not with any name. Like if we have file.java but i want to save my file with only .java not want give any name. Is it is possible in java. If possible than how we can compile and run this file from cmd

Answer (score 1):

If you try it you get

```
.java:1: error: class A is public, should be declared in a file named A.java
```

So probably not.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you've slightly misunderstood the file naming rules. If your class is `public` then you will get the error `class Cat is public, should be declared in a file named Cat.java` since the JLS mandates this. However, there's nothing stopping you from creating a file called `.java` and compiling it as long as it doesn't contain a `public class`. If it did contain a `public class`, then you would have to give the `class` no name, something that isn't possible in Java.

**Contents of file `.java`**

```
class Cat {
    private final static int four = 42;
    private final int age;
    public Cat(int age) {
        this.age = four;
    }
    public void meow() {
        System.out.println("Meow.");
    }
}
```

**Command**

```
javac .java
```

**Output**

One file aptly named `Cat.class` containing all necessary components for simulating a real cat.

That said, please don't do something like this for the sake of your own and anyone who ever looks at your codes' sanity.

Comment: +1 Since it's thorough and correct. Still not sure why you'd ever want to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can compile with like inside a directory without being specific to file name

```
javac  *.java
```